# Using multiple WHEN, WHERE conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have a table as like below

```
ID  Primary  Date
12    0     6/6/2011
12    1     6/24/2010
12    0     5/20/2009
12    1     6/21/2010
13    0     5/18/2010
13    0     6/18/2016
13    0     6/24/2010
```

I've to insert into other table, lets say #temp

I should write a select query so that the result should be as below:

```
ID   Primary   Date
12     1      6/21/2010
13     0      5/18/2010
```

Condition:

If any `id` contains `Primary -> 1` then we should consider the record which is having primary as 1 
(no need to consider the `primary->0` record) and the earliest date i.e., min (date)

if the `id` has Primary as 0 then we should consider the record with the earliest date i.e., min (date)

I tried with case statements and using With CTE etc.. in the select query but didnt get the expected result..

can any one help me to solve this..

Comment: Post the code of your last attempt so we can debug it.

Comment: This is very answerable and all the information needed to provide a solution is here. No idea why this was put on hold as too broad.  I can solve this problem easily and several people have already put in what seem to be very viable possibilities.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: But we should not use subqueries

Comment: You mentioned in your question, already you try with CTE and didn't get the correct result. I didn't use subquery, I just use the CTE only.

Comment: Lemme try your updated solution.. :) @Dinesh

Comment: This looks like school (university) question. I am gobsmacked by the fact that non of the gurus offered a simple conditional `GROUP BY` as a solution: `SELECT ID, MAX( [Primary] ) AS MaxPrimary,
 CASE
  WHEN MAX( [Primary] ) = 1 THEN MIN( CASE [Primary] WHEN 1 THEN [Date] ELSE NULL END )
  ELSE MIN( [Date] )
 END
FROM #TestData
GROUP BY ID`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,.

```
;with testcte(prim,date,RN)
as
(select prim,min(date),ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by prim order by date) RN
from datetest
group by prim,date)
select prim,date from testcte where RN = 1
```

OR

```
select ID, max([primary]) [Primary],case when max([primary]) = 1 then min(date) when max([primary]) = 0 then min(date) end [Date]
from datetest group by id
```

Comment: we should not use sub queries :(

Comment: Its not giving the expected result @DineshDB

Comment: Can u give me a better solution,using the CTE!

Comment: Try the second answer, think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then this worked fine for me. Of course since it has subqueries it's not very suitable for routines used often, specially on tables with a lot of data. But this works, specially if you just want to do a one-time import.

```
declare @temp TABLE (Id int, [Primary] BIT, [Date] Date)

insert into @temp (Id, [primary], [date]) VALUES (12, 0, GetDate())
insert into @temp (Id, [primary], [date]) VALUES (12, 0, GetDate())
insert into @temp (Id, [primary], [date]) VALUES (12, 1, GetDate())
insert into @temp (Id, [primary], [date]) VALUES (12, 0, GetDate())
insert into @temp (Id, [primary], [date]) VALUES (13, 0, GetDate())
insert into @temp (Id, [primary], [date]) VALUES (13, 0, GetDate())

select * from @temp

SELECT
[Id],
[Primary],
MIN([date])
FROM @temp tt
WHERE
((SELECT Count(*) FROM @temp t WHERE t.[Primary] = 1 and t.Id = tt.Id) > 0 and tt.[Primary] = 1)
    OR (SELECT Count(*) FROM @temp t WHERE t.[Primary] = 1 and t.Id = tt.Id) = 0
GROUP BY Id, [Primary]
```

Comment: we should not use sub queries :(

Answer (score 0):

thy this:

```
SELECT ID, Primary, MIN(Date)
FROM table
WHERE
(
    ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID
           FROM table
           WHERE Primary = 1)
    AND Primary = 1
)
OR
ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID
           FROM table
           WHERE Primary = 1)
GROUP BY ID, Primary
```

Comment: we should not use sub queries :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's make some test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID int, [Primary] int, Date datetime)
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, [Primary], Date)
VALUES
(12,0,'2011-06-06')
,(12,1,'2010-06-24')
,(12,0,'2009-05-20')
,(12,1,'2010-06-21')
,(13,0,'2010-05-18')
,(13,0,'2016-06-18')
,(13,0,'2010-06-24')
```

You could use a query like this which uses one subquery to look at the results where `primary = 1` and another to look at the results where `primary = 0`. It then uses coalesce to return the value from the `primary = 1` subquery if it exists, otherwise it gets the value from the other query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t.ID
,CASE 
    WHEN pr.date IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 1
    WHEN np.date IS NOT NULL
        THEN 0
 END [Primary]
,COALESCE(pr.date, np.date) [date]
INTO #Temp
FROM #TestData t
LEFT JOIN --Primary = 1 Results
    (
        SELECT 
        a.ID
        ,MIN(date) date
        FROM #TestData a
        WHERE [Primary] = 1
        GROUP BY ID
    ) pr
ON t.ID = pr.ID
LEFT JOIN --Primary = 0 Results
    (
        SELECT 
        ID
        ,MIN(date) date
        FROM #TestData 
        WHERE [Primary] = 0
        GROUP BY ID
    ) np
ON t.ID = np.ID
```

Which gives these results into #temp

```
ID  Primary date
12  1       2010-06-21 00:00:00.000
13  0       2010-05-18 00:00:00.000
```

Also, please don't use names like `Primary` and `Date` for field names. These are reserved words in SQL and will cause you no end of problems.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: Thanks Benner!.. But need it without using subqueries and in a simplified manner :) I'm trying to frame the query